# Linq equivalent in Android Sqlite?

Tags: android, linq, sqlite, android-sqlite

Are there anything like LINQ available in Java for SQLite inside Android?
I mean something that can detect relations among table and handle Queries in objcet model?
It is so time consuming to handle all DB queries manually and avoid errors such as misspelling.

Comment: there are various orm frameworks, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at:

[Active Android](http://www.activeandroid.com)

and

[GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/)

These are great ORM solutions.